# HTML, A href and name

Tags: html

Which one is the correct way or using `a` tag in this context?

```
<a name="test">Test</a>
```

or

```
<a name="test></a>Test
```

Comment: Have you done a test to see which one would be the best?

Comment: Technically the first option, however using ```name="test"``` i am not sure of

Comment: Also, what di you use the attribute `name` for?

Comment: The `name` attribute on an anchor element is Deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#deprecated_attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
the correct is the first one
```

Test

Answer (score 1):

The first example is correct
`<a name="test">Test</a>`

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is `<a href="url">link text</a>`

"name" is not a valid attribute for `<a>` tag. The allowed attributes are:
download, href, hreflang, media, ping , referrerpolicy, rel, target and type. Of course, `<a>` tag also allows global attributes and event attributes in addition to these.

If you want to use custom attributes consider using `data-` format like `data-name`
eg.
`<a href="url" data-name="custom_name">link text</a>`